# what is the formula for excel when cell value changing from 0 to 1, the calculation formula in next cell will start

Tags: excel-formula, countif, calculation

what is the formula for excel when cell value changing from 0 to 1, the calculation formula in next cell will start.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$2:C2082, C582)>1, 1,0)
```

I search for any duplicated items in the column with the above excel formula. Once it meets any duplicates, the cell value will change to "1". Then, I want to start the calculation in another cell. Any ideas, please. Thanks.

I've tried. But I still haven't figured it out.

Comment: Your question is not clear. This may be a language problem, since it looks like English is not your first language. Excel always calculates all formulas, unless you turn on manual calculation, but even then all formulas will be recalculated when you hit F9. That's how Excel works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since I've got the answer with the following formula. [=IF(M1=1, F1-R1, "")]